# Tcolorbox gradient gray color

Tags: tcolorbox, gradient

We used `tcolorbox` with gradient shade with single color that is gray to white percentages, we checked the output in PDF the color showing CMYK mixed color, is my TeX coding correct?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter%
\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{boxonegradbegin}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.10}%
\newtcolorbox{gradientbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,sharp corners,
  frame hidden,interior style={left color=boxonegradbegin,right color=white},
  #1
}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}

\begin{gradientbox}
The Strati resulted from the 3D Printed Car Design Challenge, conducted using crowd-sourcing technologies by Local Motors, which is based in Phoenix, Arizona. The company believes it is at the forefront of the 3D Industrial Revolution and describes itself as a free online and physical workspace that enables people to turn their vehicle innovations into reality and rewards them for their contribution. The key issues discussed in the brief for the design challenge were as follows.
\end{gradientbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi TeXnicians, PDF showing CMYK color instead of Black percentages in the shading area since this is single color book.

Comment: We checked color preview, Adobe acrobat Pro-->Advanced-->Print Production-->Output Preview; Cyan-9%,Magenta-6%,Yellow-7%,Black-0% which decreased gradient value upto CMYK 0%. But we need gradient value CMYK:0,0,0,10 to CMYK:0,0,0,0(single color layout)

Comment: Any idea about this?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not able to help you

Comment: TeXpert anyone can clear my doubt?